# How to use JWrapper graphical interface

Tags: java, jwrapper

I have a jar program and Im trying to use JWrapper to create an installer for windows and for mac. This is the first time I try this so forgive me for ths basic question, but I cant figure out how to fill in the different fields in the JWrapper interface. For example, Im asked to provide the classpath. I tried pointing to the folder which contains the jars which my program uses but that doesnt work. I am also asked to provide the path to "Files". What do they mean by that? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I would be also interested in a Tutorial, which can be UNDERSTOOD :) The "Getting Started"-Section on their website is not very helpful to me

Comment: Have you found a tutorial for JWrapper Gui? if yes, could you please send me the URL. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I havent